# Do not hang while adding a large amount of items to a list box

Tags: vb.net

I am building a program that requires to put a huge amount of items into a listbox.

The issue am facing is that it hangs while adding it and the amount of time required to add all of the items can be hours.

Is there anyway to add a large amount of items and not hang the app?

Comment: I highly suggest [turning Option Strict on](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/311329). You appear to be doing lots of strange implicit data conversions. For example, you're converting `sequence` to an array, then storing it in a string called `attempt`. Also, if this code is running on the form that contains the listbox, there wouldn't be any reason to try to run it from another thread. How do you know it is this code that causes your form to hang?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. You didn't post the start of the function (Sub) for this code, so I wasn't sure if it was part of a bigger system that could be causing problems. jmcilhinney's advice below should lead you in the right direction, but definitely start using Option Strict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Justin Ryan that your code doesn't really make sense as it is.  You should turn `Option Strict On` and write proper code.

That's by the by though.  Your scenario is tailor made for a `BackgroundWorker` so you obviously haven't tried very hard.  How does a `BackgroundWorker` work?  You do the background work in the `DoWork` event handler, update the UI as you go in the `ProgressChanged` event handler and update the UI when you're done in the `RunWorkerCompleted` event handler.

- What's your background work?  The loop creating the hashes.
- What UI updates do you need to perform as you go?  Adding attempts to
  `log.Items`.
- What UI update do you need to perform when you're done?  Setting `Crack.Text`.

That's as straightforward as it gets with a `BackgroundWorker`.